# Variabile behaving differently in debugging vs. non-debugging in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I work with the GUI from Matlab R2014a.

I want to see if there is something written in an *edit* control. If it is, then the program does something. If it is not, then it does something else. The code that I wrote is this (in the KeyPressFcn callback):

```
h1=findobj('Tag','btnOK1');    %this is a button
h2=findobj('Tag','edIndexIesire'); %this is an edit
text=get(h2,'String'); %I read the content of the edit
msgbox(text); %display it in a message box
if (isempty(text)) %if the edit is empty...
    set(h1,'Enable','off'); %... then disable the button.
else %If it is not...
    set(h1,'Enable','on'); %... enable the button
end
```

So far so good. However, the value of the *text* variable seem to be different when I am debugging vs. when I am running the program by itself. In debug mode, everything works fine and the *text* variable gets the value that I am typing from the keyboard. When I am not debugging, the *text* variable takes the value what had from the previous iteration of this callback.

**Example** I want to enter the number 55. When I enter the first 5, the *text* variable is empty. When I enter the second 5, the *text* variable has the value 5.

Where am I mistaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant test just now - but I suspect this is because of the callback you are using.

The `KeyPressFcn` is activated **when you press the key** - that means that it is running before the key you are pressing has registered in the control.

The fact you see the value **you expect** in debug is a sort of optical illusion - in fact your not comparing the real situation with the debug...

Comment: Yes, you were right. The callback was the problem. Thank you very much!